# How to enable the sound via audio cable on raspberry pi running on FullPageOS?

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

I’m using a raspberry pi to display my geckoboard dashboard on TV but there is no sound.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to raspi-config (sudo raspi-config) using your terminal.

1. System Options (1 for now)
2. Audio then option 1 (for audio jack)

Check out the [Raspberry pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#changing-the-audio-output) for more infos.